# Suppress "current transaction is aborted…" messages in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I have a very big SQL dump I'm working on. The overall structure looks like this:

```sql
BEGIN;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
INSERT …;
-- … ~300K insert operations
INSERT …;
COMMIT;
```

The problem is if there is an error in any single statement, then error is shown and the message `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` is generated for EACH statement that follows it.

Why does it behave so weirdly? Is there a way to suppress the following messages? It's enough to just show the real error message and to skip transaction execution. I don't want to see ~300K meaningful error messages.

Do I need to structure my dump differently? Or is there a flag/option I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're using `psql` to send the queries to the server.
You may set the `ON_ERROR_STOP` built-in variable to `on`.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html:

```
  ON_ERROR_STOP

  By default, command processing continues after an error. When this
  variable is set to on, processing will instead stop
  immediately. In interactive mode, psql will return to the command
  prompt; otherwise, psql will exit, returning error code 3 to
  distinguish this case from fatal error conditions, which are
  reported using error code 1.
```

It may be set from outside psql with `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f script.sql`, or from inside the script or interactively with the meta-command `\set ON_ERROR_STOP on`.

`pg_dump` does not have an option to add this automatically to a dump (as far as I know, it doesn't emit any `psql` meta-command anyway, only pure SQL commands).

Comment: Oh, thanks! This works pretty great. There are a lot to learn every day. However, is there a way to add it to the dump file directly? Or does it work only as a CLI argument?